# Laptop Resume: Turn on two TVs, Suspend: turn off two TVs

Tags: usb, suspend, power-management, external-monitor

I've just started researching: USB-UIRT (**U**niversal **I**nfrared **R**eceiver/**T**ransmitter) allows any USB-equipped PC to Transmit and Receive Infrared signals to common AV equipment.

My goal is when opening laptop lid two TVs are turned on and one TV has remote control code sent to change resolution from "Natural" to "Native" which is to say 1920x1080 without 10 pixels dropped around the border.

Currently I have to use two manual TV remote controllers and in the interests of automation (and laziness?) I'd like to use a USB-UIRT.

I have three other remote controllers next to me (Blu-Ray, A/C and Window Fan) but they would be on-demand and not hooked into laptop's startup / shutdown / suspend / resume software. A reboot would not power off TVs.

Question: ***Can you share what software you have used with a USB-UIRT?***

Comment: Read `man pm-action` or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/pm-action.8.html to see where to intervene.

Comment: @waltinator I already have lots of suspend/resume hooks in systemd. My question was about USB-UIRT software recommendations.